# CW complexes as simplicial sets.

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology, simplicial-stuff

Is every CW complex the geometric realization of some simplicial set? Certainly not up to homeomorphism but maybe homotopy equivalence?

Comment: To complement: the homotopy category of simplicial sets $\operatorname{Ho}(\mathbf{S})$ (formally inverting weak equivalences), the homotopy category of topological spaces $\operatorname{Ho}(\mathbf{Top})$  (formally inverting weak homotopy equivalences) and the category of CW-complexes with morphisms homotopy classes of maps are all equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

Every CW complex is homotopy equivalent to the realization of its singular set.

Comment: Do you have a reference for this?

Comment: A reference for this fact is "Simplicial Objects in Algebraic Topology" by Peter May